# Position of "haut" for the meaning "tall" or "high"

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, ordre-des-mots

The adjective [*haut*](http://www.bertrandboutin.ca/Folder_151_Grammaire/F_f_place_adj.htm#_haut), when used in the meaning "tall" or "high", is sometimes placed before and sometimes after the noun:

> C’est un homme de haute taille.
>
> Il y a de hautes montagnes dans cette région.
>
> À marée haute, l’eau vient jusqu’ici.

What is the rule for when *haut* should be placed before or after the noun? For example, should one say

> Il y a beaucoup de hauts bâtiments à Francfort.

or

> Il y a beaucoup de bâtiments hauts à Francfort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place *"haut"* before the noun, just like other adjective that describe height like *grand*, *petit*, *long* etc.

> C’est un homme de haute taille.

*haute* can not describe *taille* because it already means "high size" in this context. You should say "grande taille"

> À marée haute, l’eau vient jusqu’ici.

*marée haute* is considered as a subject on its own rather than subject+adjective.
Also, *haute marée* isn't wrong although this is not really used

Comment: So we should say "de hauts bâtiments" and not "de bâtiments hauts"?

Comment: In this context: *Beaucoup de* + adjective + noun

Comment: @user11550 The absolute most natural thing to say is "de grands bâtiments"